# Table row edit function is not working in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want to get input fields to the table and then remove or edit rows. I'm done till removing the row but edit function is not working

**I tried the below code, it's giving correct output until submitting data to the table, even removing row is also working
but when I am trying to edit row inputs given in edit, modal is taking into submitting button and
it creates a new row instead of updating existing data in table row**

```
 <div class="card">
      <form [formGroup]="userform">
        <div class="mt-5 box">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="formgroup mt-4">
                <label>Name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row" style="margin-top: -10px;">
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-contorl" placdeholder="name">
                </div>
    
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="formgroup mt-4">
                <label>Phone number</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row" style="margin-top: -10px;">
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="text" formControlName="Phone" class="form-contorl" placdeholder="Phone number">
                </div>
    
              </div>
              <div class="form-row mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!userform.valid"
                    (click)="submit()">submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="col-md mt-4 mb-4">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
              <th>Remove</th>
              <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of listdata">
              <td><span>{{item.name}}</span></td>
              <td><span>{{item.Phone}}</span></td>
    
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeitem(item)">Remove</button></td>
              <td><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" class="btn btn-primary"
                  (click)="edit(item)">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
    
            <form [formGroup]="userform">
    
              <div class="input-group form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
              <div class="input-group form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Phone" placeholder="Phone number">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!userform.valid"
                  (click)="update()">update</button>
              </div>
            </form>`
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

> ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss'],
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
  userform: FormGroup;
  listdata: any;
  index: any;
  itemobj: any;
  constructor(private route: Router, private formbuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.listdata = [];
    this.userform = this.formbuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      Phone: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  submit(): void {
    this.listdata.push(this.userform.value);
    this.userform.reset();
  }

  update(): void {
    this.listdata[this.index] = this.itemobj;

    // this.listdata.push(this.userform.value);
    // this.userform.reset();
  }
  edit(item: any): void {
    this.userform.patchValue({
      // name:this.userform.get("name")?.value,
      // Phone:this.userform.get("Phone")?.value
      name: item.name,
      Phone: item.Phone,
    });
    this.itemobj = item;
    this.index = this.listdata.indexOf(item);
  }

  removeitem(element: any) {
    this.listdata.forEach((value: any, index: any) => {
      if (value == element) this.listdata.splice(index, 1);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ISSUES

1. You should **not use the same `[formGroup]` name for your create & edit form**. As when you click 'Edit' Contact record, both of your forms (create, edit) will bind with the value.
2. In `update` method, you are storing the `Contact` item value (`itemObj`) which is assigned the value in `edit` method. **The `itemObj` value is not updated based on the form value**. Hence your selected Contact is not updated with new value.

```
update(): void {
    this.listdata[this.index] = this.itemobj;
}
```

---

### SOLUTION

1. Apply another [formGroup] name for your edit form and create another `formbuilder` for it.
2. Use `<form>.value` to retrieve the value from your edit form and next update to the array.

```
let user = this.editUserForm.value;
```

Your source code should be as:

> contact.component.html (for edit form only)

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
    
            <form [formGroup]="editUserForm">
    
              <div class="input-group form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name">
              </div>
              <div class="input-group form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Phone" placeholder="Phone number">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!editUserForm.valid"
                  (click)="update()">update</button>
              </div>
            </form>`
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

> contact.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: `./contact.component.html`,
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit  {
userform: FormGroup;
editUserForm; FormGroup;
  listdata: any;
  index: any;
  itemobj: any;

  constructor(private route: Router, private formbuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.listdata = [];
    this.userform = this.formbuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      Phone: ['', Validators.required],
    });

    this.editUserForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      Phone: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  submit(): void {
    this.listdata.push(this.userform.value);
    this.userform.reset();
  }

  update(): void {
    let user = this.editUserForm.value;

    this.listdata[this.index] = user;
    this.editUserForm.reset();
  }
  
  edit(item: any): void {
    this.editUserForm.patchValue({
      // name:this.userform.get("name")?.value,
      // Phone:this.userform.get("Phone")?.value
      name: item.name,
      Phone: item.Phone,
    });
    this.itemobj = item;
    this.index = this.listdata.indexOf(item);
  }

  removeitem(element: any) {
    this.listdata.forEach((value: any, index: any) => {
      if (value == element) this.listdata.splice(index, 1);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ffwtdy)

Comment: It's working thankyou, but can we write this whole code in any simpler way..? I mean I'm getting output as expected but I'm not understanding this ts file code.

Comment: Do you mean the solution/changes that I made in.ts file? If yes, what I had changed are 1. create another `FormGroup` for edit form. 2. Binding selected user's value to edit form. 3.  Retrieve edit form's value and update to array by index.